# how to send parameter using GET or POST method to php page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying somthing else that sends parameter form file.php (that has javascript written        `<script> .... </script>`). I am trying to pass parameter to other file file2.php but I am failed to do so. (sorry for my bad english). here is the code that i am trying.

**file.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeThis(){

var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = formInput;
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "event2.php?theInput"= + formInput, true );
xmlHttp.send();
return xmlHttp.responseText;    
}

 </script>

 <!--  <p>You wrote: <span id='newText'></span> </p> -->
     <textarea id="theInput" style="height:200px;">Write Here</textarea>
    <input type='button' onclick='changeThis()' value='See what you wrote'/>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET["theInput"];
  echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: Why are you not using jQuery? It really make life easier for everything in js...

Comment: jQuery really does very little to make life easier unless you are targeting older browsers which don't have modern APIs like `classList` and `querySelector`.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not agree about your answer but anyways, it's not the question here :)

Comment: actually m beginner and started to doing extra work. so that i should clear my concepts. i have also studied other post but again as beginner i found them hard.

Comment: You should read up on cross-site scripting because that code is vulnerable to such attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You've commented out `<span id='newText'></span>`, so `document.getElementById('newText')` will be `undefined` so trying to assign a value to `document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML` will throw an exception and your function will terminate at that point.

Either stop trying to modify an element you've removed, or put the element back.

---

Other that that, this will successfully send the data (although you really should URL Encode the user input you are stuffing into the query string). It just won't do anything with the response as you don't have a `load` or `readystatechange` event handler on the XHR object.

Comment: but it is still not going in "file2.php". i tested by placing alert("hi"). at least it should have shown alert.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the results. You are making an HTTP request with Ajax, the response is returned to JavaScript (and not automatically rendered as a webpage). You have to process the response yourself.

Comment: See also, the last sentence of my answer above and [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20928713/19068)

Comment: is that not response: "return xmlHttp.responseText;" ? in line before script ends? any suggestion.

Comment: Since Ajax is asynchronous, [no, it isn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225667/how-to-return-ajax-response-text), and, even if it was, you are just returning a value. You don't try to do anything with that value.

Answer (score 0):

Your first scipt could work, just  change :

```
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "file2.php?theInput=" + formInput, true );
```

Wrong :

```
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "event2.php?theInput"= + formInput, true );
```

Your php filename seems to be **file2.php** and not **event2.php**

You must have **=** between  the **""**

your old script corriged :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeThis(){
 var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
 document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = formInput;
 var xmlHttp = null;
 xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlHttp.open( "GET", "file2.php?theInput=" + formInput, true );
 xmlHttp.send();
 return xmlHttp.responseText;     
}

</script>

 <p>You wrote: <span id='newText'></span> </p> 
 <textarea id="theInput" style="height:200px;">Write Here</textarea>
<input type='button' onclick='changeThis()' value='See what you wrote'/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes if you want, but your second file name is really : "file2.php" ?

Comment: yes but i dont know what is going on. i for debug place alert but not going to display alert or echo. here is the link. http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1388943586

Comment: i have uploaded the file.

Comment: Sir u checked that file?

Comment: Yes, there is no mistake, i test them, they works perfectly...but for the alert, you can't write it on a php file whithout indicate `<script="javascript"></script>`.

Comment: Write 'Hello' as example in 'Write Here' then click on the button, and the text will appear after 'You wrote:'

Answer (score 0):

**file.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeThis(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file2.php",
    data: {theInput:theInput},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data){
        $('#newText').html(data.newText);
        }
    });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<span id='newText'></span>
<textarea id="theInput" style="height:200px;">Write Here</textarea>
<input type='button' onclick='changeThis()' value='See what you wrote'/>

</body>
</html>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php
        $arr = array();
        $arr['newText'] = '';

        if(isset($_REQUEST['theInput']))
        {
            $arr['newText'] = $_REQUEST['theInput'];
        }

        die(json_encode($arr));
?>
```

Comment: thanks for writting but  i dont know what is jquery is that for java??. i am much spending time for javascript. is related to javascript??

Comment: The purpose of jQuery is to make it much easier to use JavaScript on your website. Do you have tried my example?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure event2.php and file2.php is same file. then try to use escape .

```
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "event2.php?theInput="= + encodedURIComponent(formInput), true)
```

Comment: `escape` is deprecated. The correct tool to use here is `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: yes escape is deprecated. encodedURIComponent should use. thanks M.